Optuna Hyperband Algorithm Not Following Expected Model Training Scheme
I have observed an issue while using the Hyperband algorithm in Optuna. According to the Hyperband algorithm, when min_resources = 5, max_resources = 20, and reduction_factor = 2, the search should start with an initial space of 4 models for bracket 1, with each model receiving 5 epochs in the first round. Subsequently, the number of models is reduced by a factor of 2 in each round and search space should also reduced by factor of 2 for next brackets i.e bracket 2 will have  initial search space of 2 models, and the number of epochs for the remaining models is doubled in each subsequent round. so total models should be 11 is expected but it is training lot's of models.
link of the article:- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06560.pdf
import optuna
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Dropout
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


# Toy dataset generation
def generate_toy_dataset():
    np.random.seed(0)
    X_train = np.random.rand(100, 10)
    y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(100,))
    X_val = np.random.rand(20, 10)
    y_val = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(20,))
    return X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val

X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val = generate_toy_dataset()

# Model building function
def build_model(trial):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=trial.suggest_int('unit_input', 20, 30),
                    activation='selu',
                    input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))

    num_layers = trial.suggest_int('num_layers', 2, 3)
    for i in range(num_layers):
        units = trial.suggest_int(f'num_layer_{i}', 20, 30)
        activation = trial.suggest_categorical(f'activation_layer_{i}', ['relu', 'selu', 'tanh'])
        model.add(Dense(units=units, activation=activation))
        if trial.suggest_categorical(f'dropout_layer_{i}', [True, False]):
            model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    optimizer_name = trial.suggest_categorical('optimizer', ['adam', 'rmsprop'])
    if optimizer_name == 'adam':
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    else:
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop()

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='val_auc')])

    return model

def objective(trial):
    model = build_model(trial)
    # Assuming you have your data prepared
    # Modify the fit method to include AUC metric
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), verbose=1)
    
    # Check if 'val_auc' is recorded
    auc_key = None
    for key in history.history.keys():
        if key.startswith('val_auc'):
            auc_key = key
            print(f"auc_key is {auc_key}")
            break
    
    if auc_key is None:
        raise ValueError("AUC metric not found in history. Make sure it's being recorded during training.")
    
    # Report validation AUC for each model
    
    if auc_key =="val_auc":
        step=0
    else:
        step = int(auc_key.split('_')[-1])
    
    auc_value=history.history[auc_key][0]
    trial.report(auc_value, step=step)
    print(f"prune or not:-{trial.should_prune()}")
    if trial.should_prune():
        raise optuna.TrialPruned()

    return history.history[auc_key]

# Optuna study creation
study = optuna.create_study(
    direction='maximize',
    pruner=optuna.pruners.HyperbandPruner(
        min_resource=5,
        max_resource=20,
        reduction_factor=2
    )
)

# Start optimization
study.optimize(objective)


